# Using promises in JS /Node JS it loops through every object every time

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, promise

I am trying to make a program that verifies if links are broken or working. I am new to JS and new to promises. I am testing a markdown file that contains one broken link and one working, and apparently, everytime I run the code it runs twice (one for each link, if I add 3 links it runs three times).

This is the output I receive

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGhJC.png)

and this is my code

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const inputPath = process.argv[2];
const inputOptions = process.argv[3];
const inputOptionsTwo = process.argv[4];

let okLinks = [];
let okLinksCount = 0;
let notOkLinks = [];
let notOkLinksCount = 0;


const checkFilePath = () => {
    let pathExt = path.extname(inputPath);
    if (pathExt == '.md') {
        console.log('md file')
        parseFile(inputPath);
    } else {
        console.log('file not recognized');
    }
};




const parseFile = (inputPath) => {
    fs.readFile(inputPath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (!err) {
            const regex = new RegExp(/(https?:\/\/[^\s\){0}]+)/g);
            const links = data.match(regex);
            if (links) {
                //function to validate, pass the links as parameter
                validateLinks(links);
            } else {
                console.log('no links found');
            }
        } else {
            //error reading files
            console.log('an error ocurred');
            console.error(error.message);
        }
    });
};


const validateLinks = (links) => {

    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        const p = new Promise(resolve => {

            fetch(links[i])
                .then(res => {

                    if (res.status >= 400) {
                        notOkLinksCount++;
                        notOkLinks.push(links[i] + ' FAIL : ' + res.status);
                    } else {
                        okLinks.push(links[i] + ' OK : ' + res.status);
                        okLinksCount++;

                    }
                    console.log('f');

                    if (inputOptions === '--validate') {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            console.log(notOkLinks);
                            console.log(okLinks);
                        }, 500);
                    } else if (inputOptions === '--stats' && inputOptionsTwo === '--validate') {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            console.log('Total: ' + links.length + '\n' + 'Ok: ' + okLinksCount);
                            console.log('Broken: ' + notOkLinksCount);
                            console.log(notOkLinks);
                            console.log(okLinks);
                        }, 2800);
                    } else if (inputOptions === '--stats') {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            console.log('Total: ' + links.length + '\n' + 'Ok: ' + okLinksCount);
                        }, 2800);
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error');
                });


        })
    }

}




checkFilePath();
```

Comment: are you sure that it's *running* twice and not just *logging to the console* twice ?

Comment: `validateLinks()` is a bit strangely implemented which makes me wonder if that's part of why you're confused.  It's a `for` loop (iterating through all the links) and then `fetch()` each of them.   But, the overall loop is wrapped in a promise, but you never resolve that promise so you have no way of knowing when all the `fetch()` operations are done and, in fact, all the `fetch()` operations are running in parallel and will complete in random order (and thus log in random order).  This will likely lead to confusing in the reading of your output log.

Comment: And, the code contains a number of `setTimeout()` functions that just log data, again confusing the output even further so there's no way you can have any idea what the timing of all the output is.

Comment: Can you use the [`await`/`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) syntax in your environment? It should make understating the promised code a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are you able to use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) syntax in your environment then it will make the reasoning of promises easier.

Currently the code does not wait for asynchronous code to complete, which is I think why the `setTimeouts` have been added. Used like this they are flakey because they are making a guess at how long the code would take to be complete rather than actually waiting until it completes or errors.

Try and avoid mixing callbacks into promise code like `fs.readFile`, Node provides an [`fs` promise API now](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api).

The [Bluebird promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) provides some helpers and [`Promise.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) or [`Promise.filter`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.filter.html) for dealing with arrays.  Also [`Promise.delay`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.delay.html) if you did need to use `setTimeout` for some other reason.

Combining all that means a fair bit of restructuring of your code.

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const parseFile = async (inputPath) => {
    try {
        const data = await fsp.readFile(inputPath, 'utf8')
        const regex = new RegExp(/(https?:\/\/[^\s\){0}]+)/g);
        const links = data.match(regex);
        if (!links) {
            return console.log('no links found');
        } 
        //function to validate, pass the links as parameter
        return validateLinks(links);
    } catch (error) {
        //error reading files
        console.error('An error occurred processing '+inputPath);
        throw error
    }
};

const checkLink = async (link) => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(link)
        if (res.status >= 400) {
            const error = new Error(`'Request failed for ${link} with ${res.status}`)
            error.res = res
            error.status = status
            throw error
        }
        return link;
    }
    catch (error) {
        error.link = link
        throw error
    }
}

const validateLinks = async (links) => {
    const notOkLinks = [];
    const okLinks = await Promise.filter(links, async link => {
        try {
            return checkLink(link)
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error('Error for %s', link, error);
            notOkLinks.push(error)
            return false
        }
    })

    return {
        okLinks,
        notOkLinks,
    }
}
```

Then you can reimplement the `checkFilePath` to `await parseFile()` and deal with  the logging of `okLinks` and `notOkLinks` that are returned in an object. Remove all the `setTimeout`s because the `await` will have waited for promises to finish before continuing on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You should not use timeouts, use promise.all to wait for processing to complete (or async await). The reason for the multiple logs in your code is that you create the logging timeouts *inside the loop* in which you create the promises, so you create a log function for every link, rather than just once.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const inputPath = process.argv[2];
const inputOptions = process.argv[3];
const inputOptionsTwo = process.argv[4];

let okLinks = [];
let okLinksCount = 0;
let notOkLinks = [];
let notOkLinksCount = 0;

const checkFilePath = () => {
  let pathExt = path.extname(inputPath);
  if (pathExt === '.md') {
    console.log('md file');
    parseFile(inputPath);
  } else {
    console.log('file not recognized');
  }
};

const parseFile = (fp) => {
  fs.readFile(fp, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (!err) {
      const regex = new RegExp(/(https?:\/\/[^\s\){0}]+)/g);
      const links = data.match(regex);
      if (links) {
        // function to validate, pass the links as parameter
        validateLinks(links);
      } else {
        console.log('no links found');
      }
    } else {
      // error reading files
      console.log('an error ocurred');
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  });
};

const validateLinks = (links) => {
  let promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    promises.push(
      fetch(links[i]).then(res => {
        if (res.status >= 400) {
          notOkLinksCount++;
          notOkLinks.push(links[i] + ' FAIL : ' + res.status);
        } else {
          okLinks.push(links[i] + ' OK : ' + res.status);
          okLinksCount++;
        }
        console.log('f');
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      })
    );
  }
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    if (inputOptions === '--validate') {
      console.log(notOkLinks);
      console.log(okLinks);
    } else if (inputOptions === '--stats' && inputOptionsTwo === '--validate') {
      console.log('Total: ' + links.length + '\n' + 'Ok: ' + okLinksCount);
      console.log('Broken: ' + notOkLinksCount);
      console.log(notOkLinks);
      console.log(okLinks);
    } else if (inputOptions === '--stats') {
      console.log('Total: ' + links.length + '\n' + 'Ok: ' + okLinksCount);
    }
  });
};


checkFilePath();
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to use promise.all but did not quite understand how it works, but this is great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> it loops through every object every time

Not exactly. The problem occurs in `validateLinks()`, which is essentially like this:

```
const validateLinks = (links) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        const p = new Promise(resolve => {
            fetch(links[i]).then(res => {
                if (res.status >= 400) {
                    notOkLinks.push(links[i] + ' FAIL : ' + res.status);
                } else {
                    okLinks.push(links[i] + ' OK : ' + res.status);
                }
                console.log(notOkLinks); // <<<<<
                console.log(okLinks); // <<<<<
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error');
            });
        })
    }
}
```

Two issues here:

1. The two `console.log()` statements are executed immediately after the `.push()` statements, which is too early. They should be executed only when all the asynchronous activity is complete - ie when all the Promises generated in the for loop have settled.
2. `validateLinks()` should return an aggregated promise in order to allow the function's caller to be informed of asynchronous completion.

Personally, I would put all the Promise chaining logic and the logging of results in the highest level function, `checkFilePath()`, and relegate `parseFile()` and `validateLinks()` to low level workers.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const inputPath = process.argv[2];
const inputOptions = process.argv[3];
const inputOptionsTwo = process.argv[4];
const checkFilePath = () => {
    let pathExt = path.extname(inputPath);
    if (pathExt == '.md') {
        console.log('md file');
        // Form the entire promise chain here.
        return parseFile(inputPath)
        .then(validateLinks)
        .then(validated => {
            // `validated` is an array of "inspection objects" - either {link, res} or {link, error}.
            // Compose the `okLinks` & `notOkLinks` arrays ...
            const okLinks = validated.filter(o => !o.error).map(o => `${o.link} OK: ${o.res.status}`);
            const notOkLinks = validated.filter(o => !!o.error).map(o => `${o.link} FAIL: ${o.error.message}`);
            // ... and log the results
            if (inputOptions === '--validate') {
                console.log(notOkLinks);
                console.log(okLinks);
            } else if (inputOptions === '--stats' && inputOptionsTwo === '--validate') {
                console.log('Total: ' + validated.length + '\n' + 'OK: ' + okLinks.length);
                console.log('Broken: ' + notOkLinks.length);
                console.log(notOkLinks);
                console.log(okLinks);
            } else if (inputOptions === '--stats') {
                console.log('Total: ' + validated.length + '\n' + 'OK: ' + okLinks.length);
            } else {
                console.log('invalid inputOptions');
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('file not recognized');
    }
};
const parseFile = async (inputPath) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(inputPath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                const links = data.match(new RegExp(/(https?:\/\/[^\s\){0}]+)/g));
                if (links && links.length) {
                    resolve(links);
                } else {
                    reject(new Error('no links found'));
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
const validateLinks = async (links) => {
    // map `links` to an array of Promises and aggregate with Promise.all()
    return Promise.all(links.map(link => {
        return fetch(link)
        .then(res => {
            if(res.status >= 400) {
                throw new Error(res.status);
            } else {
                return { link, res }; // validated
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // expected and unexpected errors will end up here
            return { link, error }; // not validated
        });
    }));
}
checkFilePath();
```